# Get Failure Notification Email when sending from a Distribution List (DL) in .NET

Tags: .net, smtpclient, mailmessage

I am using .NET to send emails. I am using a DL for MailMessage.From. How can the DL itself or an individual receive failure notification when the email fails to be sent for any reason like wrong recipient email id ?

Failure notificaiton emails are not sent to DL. Though they do work when using individual's email id in "FROM". I tried to add an individual email id in ReplyTo, it didn't work.

Please suggest.

Comment: Could you surround your code with a try-catch that sends an email to the desired user? Can you provide some code?

Comment: It is the usual .NET mail sending code.

Comment: Yes, no exception occurs.

Comment: You could create a `WrongRecipientException` that way your try catch could work.

Answer (score 0):

As you have already mentioned in your question that you do get failure notifications when you specify an individual email address in the "from" address, I will answer the second part of your question where you want the notifications to be delivered to a DL.

Delivery Status Notifications to DL's are prohibited as per SMTP Service Extension for Delivery Status Notifications (DSNs) [rfc 3461](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3461.txt). As per this protocol in section **5.2.7.1 mailing lists** :

> it is important that DSNs NOT be issued by both the MTA (to report
> successful delivery to the list), and the list (to report message
> rejection using a "failure" DSN.)

This is why your code will work fine with individual email addresses but will not work with a DL

Answer (score 0):

You should try SmtpFailedRecipientsException. Please find the code snippet here

```
public static void RetryIfBusy(string server)
    {
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("ben@contoso.com");
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("jane@contoso.com");
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
        // message.Subject = "Using the SmtpClient class.";
        message.Subject = "Using the SmtpClient class.";
        message.Body = @"Using this feature, you can send an e-mail message from an application very easily.";
        // Add a carbon copy recipient.
        MailAddress copy = new MailAddress("Notifications@contoso.com");
        message.CC.Add(copy);
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
        // Include credentials if the server requires them.
        client.Credentials = (ICredentialsByHost)CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        Console.WriteLine("Sending an e-mail message to {0} using the SMTP host {1}.",
             to.Address, client.Host);
        try
        {
            client.Send(message);
        }
        catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException ex)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < ex.InnerExceptions.Length; i++)
            {
                SmtpStatusCode status = ex.InnerExceptions[i].StatusCode;
                if (status == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxBusy ||
                    status == SmtpStatusCode.MailboxUnavailable)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Delivery failed - retrying in 5 seconds.");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                    client.Send(message);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to deliver message to {0}", 
                        ex.InnerExceptions[i].FailedRecipient);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in RetryIfBusy(): {0}", 
                    ex.ToString() );
        }
    }
```

please refer to this link for more details
[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1s04he7(v=vs.110).aspx)